# JAVA | Error comparación array con letra: if(caracteres[0].equals("A")

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de comparar un valor de un array con una letra, pero me devuelve error. ¿Qué sucede?

Suponemos que en la posición de array caracteres[0] hay una A.

```
if(caracteres[0].equals("A")){
}
```

Error: char cannot be dereferenced

Comment: que error te devuelve? podrias agregar el eror para entender tu problema

Comment: char cannot be dereferenced

Comment: ya te comente una solucion super sencilla y facil, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar `char` se utiliza el operador `==` no `equals()`

```
if(caracteres[0] == 'A'){
}
```

Y comillas simples, las comillas dobles son para `String`

Comment: buenas respuesta, pero yo recomendaria usar int si intentas comparar un entero con un string.

Answer (score 2):

Eso se debe a que un `array` de tipo `char` (`char[]`), no posee el método `equals()`, para ello podrías utilizar en reemplazo de `char[]`, el tipo de dato `Character[]` el cual si posee el método que necesitas:

```
    Character[] caracteres  = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

    if(caracteres[0].equals('A')){
        System.out.println("Mismo");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Diferente");
    }
```

Adicional a eso `caracteres[0].equals("A")`, para comparar dos caracteres debería ser con comilla simple (`'`), es decir, `caracteres[0].equals('A')` , por otra parte si deseas seguir usando un `array` de tipo `char` simplemente podrías usar `caracteres[0] == ('A')`.

Te dejo información sobre [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) y [char](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (dato primitivo)

Answer (score 2):

te comento ...

> The type char is a primitive -- not an object -- so it cannot be dereferenced

El tipo char es primitivo, no un objeto, por lo que no se puede desreferenciar

**Importante**:En Java nunca trabajas con objetos directamente; siempre trabaja con referencias ("punteros") a objetos.

en tu caso podrias crear un variable string asi:

```
String str="A";
```

no deberias definir un char como entero por en caracter(string)  deberias definir un int para el numero y un string para el texto y simplemente usando la funcion equals te funcionaria bien , te dejo un simple ejemplo.

y tu codigo deberia estar asi:

```html
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        String texto = "A";
      int entero = 1;
      

System.out.println(texto.equals(entero));

    }
}
```

Te invito a que mires estos link que son muy interesante que te podrian ayudar:

[introduccion a tipo de datos en java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

[Que son los char en java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

[conoce mas sobre el metodo equals() de java](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-equals)

[introduccion a los string en java](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/clases1/string.htm)

[como comparar un array con una letras  - excelente tutorial](https://www.java67.com/2014/05/how-to-compare-two-arrays-in-java-string-int-example.html)

[otra solucion en stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527114/char-cannot-be-dereferenced-error)

[String - oracle documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[tipo de datos - oracle documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

[Java: Primitives vs Objects and References](https://programming.guide/java/primitives-vs-objects-references.html)

Te sugiero que mires este libro sobre introduccion a java es genial:

**Introduction to Java Programming (4th Edition) [Y. Daniel Liang]**